# Sort a hash that has dates as key. (ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I want to sort a hash that has dates as the key in ascending order. My hash is:

```
date_hash = {"2018-02-09"=>{"12"=>0},
             "2018-02-08"=>{"12"=>0},
             "2018-01-09"=>{"12"=>0}}
```

I tried:

```
Hash[date_hash.sort_by{|k, _| k.to_date}]
```

but no luck. It gives the output:

```
{"2018-01-09"=>{"12"=>0},
 "2018-02-09"=>{"12"=>0},
 "2018-02-08"=>{"12"=>0}}
```

strange thing I noticed is `date_hash` comes as a sorted hash just after it has defined! why hash is not coming in the order I defined ?

in irb

```
>> date_hash = {"2018-02-09"=>{"12"=>0},"2018-02-08"=>{"12"=>0},"2018-01-09"=>{"12"=>0}}
=> {"2018-01-09"=>{"12"=>0}, "2018-02-08"=>{"12"=>0}, "2018-02-09"=>{"12"=>0}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thumb: don’t use Rails bullshit when there are old good plain ruby methods existing.

```
date_hash.sort_by { |k, _| Date.parse k }.to_h
#⇒ {"2018-01-09"=>{"12"=>0},
#   "2018-02-08"=>{"12"=>0},
#   "2018-02-09"=>{"12"=>0}}
```

Or, even without dates:

```
date_hash.sort_by { |k, _| k.split('-').map(&:to_i) }.to_h
```

Or even for dates formatted like this:

```
date_hash.sort_by(&:first).to_h
```

---

Proposed by @StefanPochmann, shorter and *maybe* even cleaner:

```
date_hash.sort.to_h
```

Comment: date_hash.sort_by { |k, _| Date.parse k }.to_h gives error NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for #<Array:0x7f26f4399398>

Comment: o_O what version of Ruby do you use? 0.2? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h

Comment: Hash[date_hash.sort_by{|k, _| Date.parse k}]  gives same output of mine

Comment: OK, within _your_ version of Ruby, **hashes are not sortable at all**. Upgrade Ruby if you want to have it sorted.

Comment: oops.. i'm working on ruby 1.8.7  . I'm looking for a solution in this version ..

Comment: I like the second one! `date_hash.sort_by { |k, _| k.split('-').map(&:to_i) }.to_h` It's brilliant.

Comment: **In Ruby 1.8 hashes are not sortable.** That said, there is no way to sort a hash in Ruby 1.8. You should convert it to the array of 2-elements arrays to have it sorted (just omit trailing `to_h`.)

Comment: Rails provides [`ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash.html)

Comment: @Stefan I don’t promote Rails in any way. You probably should post this as an answer since OP might be satisfied with this solution.

Comment: How about just `date_hash.sort.to_h`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I thought about it, but in my understanding, it’s less explicit. Maybe the intent is also is clear as within `map(&:first)`, I honestly don’t know.